# "IN" operator with empty strings in Python 3.0

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

As I am going through tutorials on Python 3, I came across the following:

```
>>> '' in 'spam'
True
```

My understanding is that `''` equals no blank spaces.

When I try the following the shell terminal, I get the output shown below it:

```
>>> '' in ' spam '
True
```

Can someone please help explain what is happening?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`''` is the empty string, same as `""`. The empty string is a substring of *every* other string.

When `a` and `b` are strings, the expression `a in b` checks that `a` is a substring of `b`. That is, the sequence of characters of `a` must exist in `b`; there must be an index `i` such that `b[i:i+len(a)] == a`. If `a` is empty, then any index `i` satisfies this condition.

This does not mean that when you iterate over `b`, you will get `a`. Unlike other sequences, while every element produced by `for a in b` satisfies `a in b`, `a in b` does not imply that `a` will be produced by iterating over `b`.

So `'' in x` and `"" in x` returns True for any string `x`:

```
>>> '' in 'spam'
True
>>> "" in 'spam'
True
>>> "" in ''
True
>>> '' in ""
True
>>> '' in ''
True
>>> '' in ' ' 
True
>>> "" in " "
True
```

Comment: If empty string, by definition, must exist in ever other string, why is it not part of the iterator set?  I.E. for i in 'spam': print(i)

Comment: @Brightlights That's an interesting question. I may have phrased that incorrectly – essentially, `a` in `b` (for strings) checks that all elements of `a` are in `b`. Thus, if `a` is empty, every element of it (which are no elements) exist in any `b`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @RushyPanchal: That's not how the check works. `a` in `b` for strings checks that `a` is a substring of `b`. For the check to evaluate to `True`, there must be some index `i` such that `b[i:i+len(a)] == a`. (This is completely different from all the other built-in sequence types.)

Comment: @Brightlights The iterator for strings iterates over every 1-character substring (i.e. over each character). The empty string is not a character of the string. However, the `in` operator, the containment check, just checks whether a string `a` is contained as a substring within `b`. You can find the empty string in every zero-length substring of a string, so `'' in x` is true for every string `x`.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes sorry, I did not mention order – I'll update my answer to include that.

Comment: @Brightlights: `for i in 'spam': print(i)` will also not print `'am'`, even though 'am' is a substring of `'spam'`.  That's because `for i in 'spam'` does not iterate over all substrings, it iterates over all characters.  If you somehow iterated over all substrings, it would indeed include `''`.

Answer (score 6):

The [string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) `''` represents the empty string. This is basically a string with a length of zero, which contains no characters.

The `in` operator is defined [for sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) to return “`True` if an item of `s` is equal to `x`, else `False`” for an expression `x in s`. For general sequences, this means that one of the items in `s` (usually accessible using iteration) equals the tested element `x`. For strings however, the `in` operator has *subsequence* semantics. So `x in s` is true, when `x` is a substring of `s`.

Formally, this means that for a substring `x` with a length of `n`, there must be an index `i` which satisfies the following expression: `s[i:i+n] == x`.

This is easily understood with an example:

```
>>> s = 'foobar'

>>> x = 'foo'
>>> n = len(x) # 3
>>> i = 0
>>> s[i:i+n] == x
True

>>> x = 'obar'
>>> n = len(x) # 4
>>> i = 2
>>> s[i:i+n] == x
True
```

Algorithmically, what the `in` operator (or the underlying `__contains__` method) needs to do is iterate the `i` to all possible values (`0 <= i < len(s) - n`) and check if the condition is true for any `i`.

Looking back at the empty string, it becomes clear why the `'' in s` check is true for every string `s`: `n` is zero, so we are checking `s[i:i]`; and that is the empty string itself for every valid index `i`:

```
>>> s[0:0]
''
>>> s[1:1]
''
>>> s[2:2]
''
```

It is even true for `s` being the empty string itself, because sequence slicing is defined to return an empty sequence when a range outside of the sequence is specified (that’s why you could do `s[74565463:74565469]` on short strings).

So that explains why the containment check with `in` always returns `True` when checking the empty string as a substring. But even if you think about it logically, you can see the reason: A substring is part of a string which you can find in another string. The empty string however can be find *between* every two characters. It’s like how you can add an infinite amount of zeros to a number, you can add an infinite amount of empty strings to a string without actually modifying that string.

Comment: Great answer that deserves to be @ the top.

Answer (score 1):

As Rushy Panchal points out, `in` inclusion operator follows set-theoretic convention and assumes that an empty string is a substring of any string.

You can try to persuade yourself why this makes sense by considering the following: let `s` be a string such that `'' in s == False`. Then `'' in s[len(s):]` better be false by transitivity (or else there is a subset of `s` that contains `''`, but `s` does not contain `''`, etc). But then `'' in '' == False`, which isn't great either. So you cannot pick any string `s` such that `'' not in s` which does not create a problem.

Of course, when in doubt, simulate it:

```
s = input('Enter any string you dare:\n')

print('' in '')
print(s == s + '' == '' + s)
print('' in '' + s)
```